# Trying to print text from a method other than paint()

Tags: java, graphics, applet

I created an applet wherein I defined a method besides overriding the **paint()** method that uses the **Graphics.drawString()** method to display a text on the canvas. The problem I'm having is that I cannot call that method. This is because the method takes a Graphics class object as an argument and I cannot pass a Graphics class object as an argument while calling that function. *(The callerMethod() is called in a certain situation.)* Please see my code below and help. Thanks.

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class MyApplet extends Applet {

    @Override
    public void init() {}

    public void callerMethod() {

        /*HERE I WANT TO CALL myPrintMethod()*/
        myPrintMethod(GRAPHICS OBJECT);
    }

    public static void myPrintMethod(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("In method myPrintMethod",20,40);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawString("In method paint",20,20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **myPrintMethod()** should be called with a Graphics object being passed as actual parameter. The Graphics object **g** of the paint method can be passed to the myPrintMethod while calling it.

```
public static void myPrintMethod(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("myPrintMethod",20,40); 
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawString("Paint method",20,20);
    myPrintMethod(g);
}
```

This will give the output:

```
Paint method

myPrintMethod
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
    Graphics g1;

    ---------------

    public void callerMethod() {
            //call myPrintMethod();         
    }

    public static void myPrintMethod() {
        //Now you can paint here also
        g1.drawString("In method myPrintMethod",20,40);
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g1 = g;
        g.drawString("In method paint",20,20);
    }
}
```

But this `myPrintMethod()` should be invoked after the `paint(.)`.

Use `Graphics2D` that provides more advanced features.

```
 Graphics2D g2d = (Grapics2D) g;
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not working. I'm sure that there are no flaws in calling the **callerMethod()** itself. I don't understand why I don't see an output.